# After cloning a repository, a folder keeps getting placed on my desktop

Tags: git, github

I am running Win10 and cloned a repository:

git clone --recursive https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3/

Since then a folder named "pbrt-v3-master" keeps appearing on my desktop, I have no use for that folder.

I don't need to be in sync with this repository all the time; just a one time deal.

How do I stop this folder appearing? Simply deleting it does not solve my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of git installed. This sounds to me like a path traversal attack. May be your system was infected by a malicious git repo?

Comment: Is it possible that this folder is part of a build or release process that is created by executing the source you've cloned?

Answer (score 1):

This folder is the clone of the repository `pbrt-v3`.  The reason it's created on your desktop is probably because when you run `git clone...` you're in the Desktop directory.  If you don't want it on your desktop, run `git clone` from a different directory.

It will not automatically sync with the github repo.  You can sync with that repo manually by running `git pull` in that directory.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't want that folder in any place. Is there a git command for that?

Comment: The whole point of cloning the repo is to "copy" it to your computer.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: The folder I don't want is the one that keeps appearing on my Desktop; the useful files are cloned into a different folder (the folder in which I executed the git clone ... command)

Comment: What's in that folder on Desktop?